# How can I deal with dart casting problem?

Tags: json, casting, dart, flutter

I have to make json data to my custom object, below code shows my model.

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class KakaoMLModel {
  final List<List<double>> jaw;
  final List<List<double>> rightEyebrow;
  final List<List<double>> leftEyebrow;
  final List<List<double>> nose;
  final List<List<double>> rightEye;
  final List<List<double>> leftEye;
  final List<List<double>> lip;

  KakaoMLModel({
    @required this.jaw,
    @required this.rightEyebrow,
    @required this.leftEyebrow,
    @required this.nose,
    @required this.rightEye,
    @required this.leftEye,
    @required this.lip
  });

  factory KakaoMLModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    print(json['jaw']);
    return KakaoMLModel(
      jaw: json['jaw'],
      rightEyebrow: json['rightEyebrow'],
      leftEyebrow: json['leftEyebrow'],
      nose: json['nose'],
      rightEye: json['rightEye'],
      leftEye: json['leftEye'],
      lip: json['lip']
    );
  }
}
```

But, when I pass json data by parameter, it occurs error message like this.

```
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<double>>'
```

`json['jaw']` format is like below

> [[0.04616761798553884, 0.5475042080412023], [0.026029605771987013,
>   0.6203330820534684], [0.014870009633410218, 0.6947797773981148], [0.01478418759402894, 0.7684331582472369], [0.03166518933198375,
>   0.8392744747251855], [0.06115956082472804, 0.9024180638379186], [0.10860571254829726, 0.9601635183836916], [0.17011504626717094,
>   1.0057204991427136], [0.25121165844788507, 1.0340586363828044], [0.3433729801681099, 1.0413332887822182], [0.4340747633053713,
>   1.0248020469426704], [0.5180659200853382, 0.9941894832935652], [0.5905636066620379, 0.949568636289012], [0.6483867917457562,
>   0.8895699510264967], [0.6935845784738898, 0.8206748353165457], [0.7288984252469625, 0.7487434227072808], [0.7554424386870936,
>   0.6755670567849011]]

How can I deal with this casting problem?

Comment: try `json['jaw'] as List<List<double>>`

Comment: or make jaw as `final List jaw` instead being specific.

Comment: Your suggestion not works

Comment: json['jaw'].cast<List<double>>() should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Nested collection generics from `dynamic` is not easy. Unfortunately the casting needs to happen all the way down at the lowest level were the elements are collections.

To take a `dynamic` which you know to be a `List` containing only `List`s, containing only `double`s, (that is `List<List<double>>` and convince the Dart runtime type system of such you'll want something like:

```
List<List<T>> _castNestedList<T>(dynamic l) =>
    (l as List).map((inner) => List<T>.from(inner)).toList();
```

The `List<T>.from` is taking each of the inner lists and copying it to a new List with the correct reified type. This is better than `List.cast` if there will be multiple reads in the list, because in the `List.cast` case there are runtime type checks on each element access.

Dealing with this type of casting is a known pain point with Dart 2. In the long term we hope to improve the usability. See discussion at https://github.com/leafpetersen/cast/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a reference to a List, then cast:

```dart
lip: (json['lip'] as List).cast<List<double>>()
```

Or to be null-aware:

```dart
lip: (json['lip'] as List)?.cast<List<double>>()
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that the _inner_ List is still a `List<dynamic>`. You've added a `cast` to the outer list, but when an element is read there will be a runtime type check to ensure that the reified type of the element is `List<double>`, but it won't be. You need to `map` over the elements to ensure each one gets the correct reified type.